# download successive files using wget

Tags: wget

I want to download pdf files as http link `http://cdn.cs50.net/2016/fall/lectures/#/week#.pdf` using **wget**, where `#` is decimal number ranging from `1` to `11`.

I've tried

```
wget http://cdn.cs50.net/2016/fall/lectures/{1..11}/week{1..11}.pdf
```

which doesn't work, so I'm using `wget -i download-list.txt`. Is there less tedious ways to do it like one-line command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use bash for loop to download your files. Try below command

```
for week in `seq 1 11`; do wget "http://cdn.cs50.net/2016/fall/lectures/$week/week$week.pdf"; done
```